# SSRS report has excessive white space but only when using IE 11.0.40

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-11

We have SSRS reports created with Reporting Services 2008 R2 and these reports are now formatting with an excessive amount of white space between the headers and the tablix.  The problem just started last week (March 22) and ONLY happens with IE version 11.0.40 (version 11.0.9600).  The reports are fine with Firefox, Chrome and IE through version 11.0.38.  We have tried using Compatibility View settings but that was not helpful.

Why is this just now appearing?  Do we need to upgrade our SSRS server or is there a fix for IE from MS?

Comment: As a test try setting ConsumeWhiteSpace to true.

Comment: @Snowlockk  Thanks.  That property was one of the first things I looked at and it was/is already set to True.

Comment: IE was auto-updated to version 11.0.41 over the weekend and now the problem has resolved itself.